# Code snippet: Possible to avoid use of new?

Tags: c++

I am trying to rewrite or use the code differently, so that I do not need to create my objects on the heap.

I have a simple event handler class that I inherit from when I want a class to be able to send an event. Its constructor pushes a pointer of the object it is creating onto a vector.

```
EventHandler::EventHandler() 
{
   EventDispatcher::getInstance().registerListener(this);
}

void EventDispatcher::registerListener(EventHandler* listener) 
{
    mListeners.push_back(listener);
}

std::vector<EventHandler*> mListeners;
```

Usage w/ objects on stack (calls invalid pointer)

```
vector<MyButtonClass> buttons;   // MyButtonClass inherits from EventHandler
MyButtonClass button(sf::Keyboard::Up);   // EventHandler contructor calls registerListener (pushing the address of button onto mListeners)
buttons.push_back(button);   // Pushes a copy of button onto buttons, while mListeners holds a pointer to button (will go out of scope)

for (auto& element : buttons)
{
    element.sendEvent();   // Error - Elements of buttons are not registered (they are copies)
}
```

Usage w/ objects on heap (works)

```
vector<MyButtonClass*> buttons;   // MyButtonClass inherits from EventHandler
MyButtonClass* button = new KeyboardButton(sf::Keyboard::Up);   // EventHandler contructor calls registerListener (pushing the address of button onto mListeners)
buttons.push_back(button);   // Pushes a copy of the pointer onto buttons (mListener and elements of buttons refer to the same object)

for (auto& element : buttons)
{
    element.sendEvent();   // Works
}
```

Comment: The object will have to be created somehow.

Comment: I don't understand this statement: "If I do not new them mListener will hold a bad pointer." Pointers to stack objects remain valid as long as the object in question is still around. However, if you push a *copy* of that object onto a vector, then you have an issue since the copy will live at a different address than the original registrant.

Comment: I don't understand this question. You say you don't want to create objects on the stack. But then you say you want to avoid `new`. The easiest way to create objects that aren't on the stack is with `new`.

Comment: In my code I often know beforehand which event handlers I'll need (e.g. one that handles a click on a specific button). They usually do not change dynamically. They can well be created file statically or globally. On the other hand there is of course no performance issue with infrequently-created objects. Unless we talk millions of objects the performance penalty from dynamic allocation is negligible, and the focus should rather be on the best design etc.

Comment: I had my terms backwards.  I mean to say I do not want to create the objects on the heap.

Comment: The issues occurs because mListeners holds a pointer that points to their location at creation.  However, the first thing I do with them is push them onto a vector (making all the pointers invalid).

Comment: pushing a pointer into a vector does not invalidate any pointers....

Comment: @Mooing Duck - mListeners holds pointers to all the objects at creation.  When I push these objects into my buttons vector all the pointers in mListeners point to original objects which go out of scope.

I am having a difficult time wording this and I am sorry for that.  I need the pointers in mListeners to point to the objects in the vector buttons.

Comment: @user870130: oooooooo I think I get it

Comment: @user870130 If you create them on the stack, they go away when the stack you created them on goes away. So if you don't want to create them on the heap, do you meet the requirements for creating them on the stack (don't need them to exist after the stack goes away)? If not, you need a third alternative.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The vector buttons does not go out of scope.  For that reason they do not need to be created on the heap, if I can properly update the pointers in mListeners to point to the objects in buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid `new` entirely unless you do something silly like `malloc`: someone, somewhere will be calling it to create your object. What you can do is use smart pointers and a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) on your `EventDispatcher` class to create and register an event handler as a single operation. Perhaps something like:

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> EventDispatcher::createListener()
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> listener = std::make_shared<T>();
    this->registerHandler(listener);
    return listener;
}
```

where `T` always extends `EventListener` (using traits or the like).

The idea here is that if `EventDispatcher` knows -- and may be the only class to know -- that all `EventHandlers` must be registered against it, then it can provide a method that will create and register a new handler. You could put that in each handler's contstructor, but then every handler would have to know and follow that pattern, which could cause problems if someone inherits from a handler later on and isn't aware of the pattern.

Using polymorphism and/or templates, you can keep that knowledge in the dispatcher, and allow it to handle it's own resources. There may be an argument that registering a handler is part of its initialization, and if that's the case, RAII says the same actor should create and register the handler.

Comment: You can't avoid new entirely and get a new object. What you can do is take the two separate operations that the OP is performing and, if they always go together, put them together. While you still have to create the object somewhere, you can do so in a safe and consistent manner.

Comment: Note that my answer is focusing more on atomizing the `push(new T())`, rather than literally not calling `new` at all ever. IMO, a method that does both operations and returns a `shared_ptr` would be a pretty smooth design. If you need to literally avoid `new`, there's no reason this can't be combined with πάντα ῥεῖ's answer (assuming that's the correct possessive).

Comment: I'd say `std::make_shared()` was introduced for this, doesn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It certainly is. My ideal solution would be to have a factory method that `make_shared`s the listener, registers, and returns it. That combines smart resource management and RAII.

Comment: Forget shared.  Store a `unique_ptr` in the vector, and `createListener` should return a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the actual type of `buttons`:

If you use e.g.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ButtonClass>> buttons;
```

as declaration you can use

```
buttons.push_back(std::make_shared<MyButtonClass>());
```

to create the instance, and leave the memory management done to `std::shared_ptr<>`, supposed that `ButtonClass` is a public base class of your `MyButtonClass`.

Comment: Surely you mean `std::unique_ptr<EventHandler>` and `std::make_unique`>?

Comment: @MooingDuck Not really _'surely'_, I've been thinking about that, but it depends on the use case and context where `buttons` should be used. `std::shared_ptr<>` should work well for any case.

Comment: I've never yet used a `shared_ptr` in real code, and disapprove of people promoting it over `unique_ptr`.  It _does_ have uses, but they're pretty rare.  Like `valarray`

Comment: @MooingDuck The point is `unique_pointer` transfers ownership, and I cant't tell from the information in the OP's question, if this is really wanted or not.

Answer (score 0):

After you updated your post and regarding your comment

> The vector buttons does not go out of scope. For that reason they do
>   not need to be created on the heap

: could it be that you just want to point at local listeners? Your example code with Buttons on the stack creates copies of the Buttons as vector elements, true. If you hold pointers to those listeners elsewhere and they need to be identical, you still could use addresses here:

```
vector<MyButtonClass *> buttons;   // Note that the vector still holds addresses
MyButtonClass button(sf::Keyboard::Up);   // EventHandler ctor calls registerListener 
                                        //(pushing the address of button onto mListeners)
buttons.push_back(&button);   // Pushes a copy of button onto buttons, 
                              // while mListeners holds a pointer to button 
                              // (will go out of scope)

for (auto element : buttons)
{
    element->sendEvent();   // calls sendEvent() on original listeners
}
```

Of course *all* pointers of the vector must point to existing objects, i.e. if they all point to local objects you cannot use the vector outside the block they have been defined in. Your example demonstrates that nicely because the vector `buttons` is declared in the same block as the object `button` it holds a pointer to.